# Que signifie "fleur" dans ce cas ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Dans cette scène de *Guignol's Band I*, où le narrateur vient de se jeter d'un wagon, Celine emploie le mot ***fleur*** :

"C'est l'instant!... Sifflet!... la porte! Juste ça referme! Je m'élance! l'entrebâille... Hop! Ça y est!... Yop là! au quai!... juste! **une fleur!** Hip! Bravo bouille! La rame repart!..."

Savez-vous à quoi "fleur" fait référence dans ce cas ?

Comment: Je ne trouve pas de source alors je ne posterai pas de réponse, mais j'ai souvent entendu "une fleur" pour signifier un petit déplacement, par ex. "Bouge-toi d'une fleur, je veux m'asseoir".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Céline fait sans doute référence à l'expression ***comme une fleur***. (ici: sans effort, facilement, sans incident)

[TLFi Fleur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fleur)

> − Locution populaire et familière
> ♦ Comme une fleur. De manière douce, ingénument. Ce qu'il faudrait, c'est le filet des gladiateurs romains que j'ai vu un jour *au ciné : avec ça, t'aurais le bul* [Bulgare] *comme une fleur et vivant !* (Vercel, *Capitaine Conan*, 1934, p. 145). Ingénument, de manière confiante.

Voici le déroulé de la scène :

| Texte | Commentaire |
| --- | --- |
| ***Clapenham !*** | Le train est en gare de Clapenham |
| **voilà !... C'est l'instant !...** | Le moment est venu |
| **Sifflet !...** | Le chef de gare donne le signal de départ du train |
| **la porte ! Juste ça referme !** | La porte est en train d'être refermée |
| **Je m'élance !** | Il se dirige rapidement vers la porte, |
| **l'entrebâille...** | l'entrouvre pour pouvoir passer, |
| **Hop !...** | saute du train |
| **Ça y est !...** | Il a réussi |
| **Yop là ! au quai !... juste !** | Il est sur le quai de la gare, juste au bon moment |
| **une fleur !** | Comme une fleur, avec grâce, sans encombre |
| **Hip ! Bravo bouille !** | Il s'autocongratule (Hip Hip Hip) |
| **La rame repart !...** | Le train quitte la gare |
| **Oh ! leurs gueules !... Ils me voyent !** | Il se moque de l'expression des visages de ceux qui sont restés dans le wagon (contrariété, surprise, colère...) quand ils le voient sur le quai |
| **Je me suis pas fait mal !... verni !** | Il se félicite d'avoir eu de la chance |
| **jailli ! youff !** | Onomatopée représentant la fuite, à rapprocher de [Vlouff](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Tintin/79418) |
| **avec ma guibolle !** | Malgré les séquelles de sa blessure à la jambe, le saut s'est passé sans encombre. |

Comment: Merci ! Est-ce usuel de dériver le sens de l'expression de "doucement, ingénument" à "facilement" ?

Comment: L'expression devait décrire à l'origine la manière dont un bouton de fleur éclot, se transforme en fleur.  Le sens de facilité, sans effort était déjà là. Aujourd'hui, l'expression est souvent ironique: *Il est arrivé comme une fleur* signifie avec insouciance, par exemple sans rien préparer, sans prévenir de son retard ou sans être invité.

Answer (score 0):

FLEUR, subst. fém.

Partie de certains végétaux contenant les organes reproducteurs, souvent odorante et ornée de vives couleurs.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language Stack Exchange.  Pourrais-tu ajouter une explication pour répondre à la question ?  Voici le [tour] du site.

Answer (score -2):

Tous les extraits proviennent de l'éditions Gallimard 2011, qui est une édition numérique.

*p. 190*

> Clapenham ! voilà !... C'est l'instant !... Sifflet !... la porte ! Juste ça
> referme ! Je m'élance ! l'entrebâille... Hop !... Ça y est !... Yop là ! au
> quai !... juste ! **une fleur** ! Hip ! Bravo bouille ! La rame repart !... Oh !
> leurs gueules !... Ils me voyent ! Je me suis pas fait mal !... verni ! jailli !
> youff ! avec ma guibolle !

Rien n'est moins sûr qu'une hypothèse que l'on puisse émettre quant à ce que Céline a voulu dire par cet abrupte interruption que créent les deux mots « une fleur ». Si l'on examine le texte de « *Guignol's Band* » on s'aperçoit que Céline fait de très nombreuses fois référence aux fleurs dans toutes sortes de contextes, et en particulier il identifie plusieurs fois jeune fille ou femme à une fleur, et même les inspirations amoureuses à un « esprit des fleurs ». Voici plusieurs cas qui ne laissent aucun doute.

*p. 21*

*François mignon, ludion d'alcool, farci gâteux, blet en discours, à basculer dans les Droits de l'Homme, au torrent d'Oubli, la peau et l'âme tournées bourriques de dégoûtation d'obéir, de se faire secouer son patrimoine, son épargne mignonne, **sa chérie, sa fleur des transes**, que ça lui sert à rien jamais de s'évertuer froncer
sérieux, que c'est plus franc à se mettre charogne et tout fainéant pisser
sous lui, que c'est toujours du kif au même, qu'il est marron dans tous
les blots, qu'il existe pas dans la course, qu'il est voué à dalle éperdu.*

*p. 257*

*Ah ! la revoilà, le samovar en équilibre... Elle repart encore dans sa
cuisine... c'est de l'allée et venue ! Elle me crie par-dessus la cloison.
« Vous me trouvez encore belle n'est-ce pas ?... Il vous a montré mes
programmes ?... j'ai joué **la Fleur merveilleuse** !... pendant vingt ans !...
Il vous l'a dit ?... »
Retour encore... maintenant sur mes genoux ! Elle minaude.*

*p. 301*

*Moi après tout je me tranquillise… puisque c'est la mode !... Je risque
rien d'une façon, d'une autre... Pourquoi me fatiguer ? Eux ils s'en font
pas... je reste assis... je reprends du thé... ça donne une contenance... la
petite me verse... Ah ! qu'elle est belle !... qu'elle est admirable ! j'en
reviens pas... quel sourire !... Tout ça pour moi !... là tous les deux !... Il
est drôle l'oncle... je réfléchis... Ah ! quelle petit espiègle mutine... elle
est malicieuse, sûrement elle sait bien ce qui se passe... Je voudrais lui
reparler du mercure.. ça me tracasse... ça me turlupine... Mais non ! elle
reste pas en place... c'est le mouvement sa nature... elle m'étourdit
même je dois le dire... elle rebondit, pirouette en lutin... dans la pièce
tout autour de moi... Quels jolis cheveux !... quel or !... quelle
gamine !... Si je dis un mot, elle me regarde... elle me prend pas au
tragique... je voudrais être tragique... je vois une malice dans ses yeux !...
Je voudrais qu'elle sourie toujours !... même de ma bêtise... Je suis idiot
avec mon complet !... Que je suis sorti exprès pour ça !... je me rends
ridicule... avec le mercure en plus ! quel effet tout de même ! Voleur !
Que j'ai honte... je suis sur des charbons... Je rougis... je pourrais rien
dire... je l'écoute elle... son babillage... c'est de l'oiseau anglais... je
comprends pas tout... Elle parle un peu vite... c'est capricieux l'anglais,
c'est joueur, c'est espiègle, celui des fillettes... ça rebondit aussi... tinte...
rit d'un rien... cabriole... palpite... Quelle gaieté !... Quels bleus reflets
clairs et puis mauves... ses yeux me prennent tout... C'est vite fait !
j'oublie... je ne vois plus rien... **elle est trop agréable fleur ! oui fleur**... je
respire... **bleuet** !... oiseau j'ai dit... j'aime mieux oiseau... tant pis ! Je suis
ensorcelé... bleuets ses yeux... une fillette... et ces jupes courtes !... Ah !
c'est trop d'attirance cochon ! les cheveux blonds éparpillés... quand elle
bondit, illumine l'air... Ah ! c'est trop beau !... je vais défaillir... C'est
adorable !...*

*p. 383*

*« Virginie ! Virginie ! je vous adore ! »
Je lui prends fermement la main... Il se passe alors là juste devant
quelque chose d'extraordinaire, toute une merveille devant nous...
Plutôt entre les arbres et nous... je m'en souviens bien exactement...
comme on dirait sur un théâtre... voilà le Bonheur ! il flambe positif,
illumine... Ça s'est jamais vu ! c'est un énorme buisson de feu ! et quelles
clartés ! rosâtres et vertes, scintillantes... avec quelques fleurs de lumière
jaune-bleu piquées dans les branches... Tout ce buisson de feu palpite...
je palpite aussi... je palpite en même temps que les roses... et puis voici
d'autres parfums... **une sorte d'esprit des fleurs** qui nous arrive... de
douceur, de charme... tout le plus tendre des roses nous frôle par
bouffées, nous enivre... quelle extase ! ravis... gâteux... éblouis... tout
éperdus de bonheur !... Ah ! mais le ciel va s'assombrir... je le vois au
loin... je grelotte...*

*P. 443*

*« Dans mon grand château frisepoulette ! Vous y serez pas mal ! Dans
ma forteresse joli cœur ! vous aurez pas froid ! »
Elle me regardait bien moqueuse... elle trottinait petit cabri... comme
ça et puis d'un pied sur l'autre... pas émue du tout... Coucou ! qu'elle
me faisait, Coucou ! le doigt sur ma tempe... elle sautait par-ci... je
marchais toujours... le dingue !
« Oui mon trésor... à triple clé ! à triple encore tour ! voilà !
– Crr ! crr ! » qu'elle partait à rire... Ah ! ça promettait... plus j'insistais
plus j'étais drôle !... J'en aurais pleuré... La mignonne... **la fleur de mon
rêve**... quelle précoce quand même ! Ah ! j'étais soufflé !...*

*P. 647*

*« Mon faible tiens moi c'est la jeune fille ! ça c'est véritable ! je les
adore quand elles sont toutes fraîches. Je m'en taperais une tous les
matins... Tiens Ferdinand ! comme elle ! **ta fleur** ! Ah ! dis donc t'as bien
choisi ! je l'aime tiens ! je l'aime c'est une merveille ! »
Elle lui faisait la cour à genoux. Elle lui faisait sa prière comme ça
tout contre le divan, son boa trempé à la traîne, elle avait enlevé ses
chaussures qu'étaient trop mouillées.*

*p. 747*

*Ça explique le malheur des dames, que tout est perdu, raclé, qu'elles rentrent **fleur du tapin**, après des huit dix heures d'efforts, désolées, malades, dégueulasses. Ces
vampires du sac... la faute à l'obscurité.*

Si on examine de nouveau le passage où se trouve l'occurrence qui concerne la question (*p. 190*), on s'aperçoit que la première image qui suit est « capturée » par les mots « Bravo Bouille » ; « bouille » est un mot populaire pour « tête » et « expression du visage » ; il ne semble pas que ce soit un rapprochement fortuit ; il est assez naturel qu'à la descente du train le passager soit rendu curieux par ce que l'on peut voir sur le quai, et ce que l'on trouve sur un quai à la descente d'un wagon de chemin de fer, c'est le plus souvent des gens, des faces. On trouve tout au long de l'œuvre les preuves de l'intérêt presque obsessif de ce passager pour les faciès, qu'il esquisse souvent en termes crus et méprisants.  De là à en conclure, que cette fleur serait en réalité une femme ou une jeune fille qu'il remarque, il n'y a qu'un pas, mais comme souvent avec Céline, on ne peut en fin de compte que pencher pour une ou plusieurs explications plutôt que d'autres sans aucune assurance de détenir la vérité.